# Good application for tracking member subscriptions?

Tags: webapp-rec

I'm starting a small non-profit, that accepts donations from "members" in the form of monthly dues.

Is there any web app that will help me track their payments?

Something easier than keeping a spreadsheet in Excel. Integration with PayPal automatically to update the data if they pay online would be nice, but it also needs to support manual entry, as some will pay via cash / check.

Comment: i am also interested in this. If you find something please let us know.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any publicly available web apps that meet your specs but (provided that you have a web host), there's a script that sounds close to what you need called the "Paypal Membership Subscription Manager" on www.codecanyon.net for $22.

http://codecanyon.net/item/paypal-membership-subscription-manager/91421

According to the developer description, it has the following features:

- Create unlimited numbers of membership subscription
- **Each membership subscription has unlimited number of rates/terms**
- Newsletter included
- Editable email templates
- Pagination, search and sort filter included
- Limit number of user registrations
- **Manually add payments**
- Graph Bar showing sales stats
- **Automated or manual user registration**
- verification Remeber me feature
- Forgot Password feature

Comment: This looks useful. It's only $20. Though I am a little wary of buying one off scripts like this from no-name people.